# Change Bootscreen with encrypted drive Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, encryption, 22.04, plymouth

Our Company will using in future our company logo in boot sequence or while the encryption is asking for password to unlock the laptop.
this will be necessary because when a laptop is stolen or something else, someone can see our logo when he will start the laptop and he can get in contact with us.
i try some guides for ubuntu 18, 19 20 etc. but nothing will work.

has some a good help in this case?

Comment: Decrypting must happen *before* anything OS related can start to load. As such, what you want can't be done.

Comment: @ChanganAuto did u think its possible to replace the dell or other manufactor logo while booting process? its important for us to save our data with an encryption so we cant disable that..

Comment: Have you tried the `plymouth-themes` package?  Eg described here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/customize-boot-splash-screen-logo-linux/
I believe the splash screen image goes into the initrd, so the encryption doesn't count (as the /boot where the initrd stored is not encrypted).

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an answer here as I was looking into this myself and this was the only relavent thing on Google.

Start off by editing the theme as you require (/usr/share/plymouth/themes)

(You'll want to replace /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt-fallback.png)

The bootscreen shown during cryptsetup is in the initrd so run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Your bootsplash will be as you wanted.

note: if the device vendor logo still shows, you can use the kernel param bgrt_disable to stop it showing